# Tengo un error que no puedo solucionar: PHP Warning: mysqli_affected_rows() expects exactly 1 parameter, 0 given in

Tags: php

Buen día, tengo el siguiente código que es para guardar datos extraídos de otras tablas, pero tengo el error que mencioné en el título el cual proviene de la línea 14 ----- if (mysqli_affected_rows()>0){  no encuentro una solución, es mi primera experiencia con php y estoy subiendo los archivos que utilicé hace unos años atrás a un vps, antes funcionaba bien ahora cambiaron algunas extensiones en php que si logré corregir, pero me encuentro con este problema.

```
<?php

include("conexion.php");
$c1=$_POST['codigot'];
$nivel=$_POST['nivel'];

$conexion = mysqli_connect("host","xxxxxx","xxxxxx","xxxxxx");
$consulta="update jueg0_r3f3 set nivel='$nivel' where codigot='$c1'";

$r=mysqli_query($conexion, $consulta);

echo(mysqli_error($conexion));
if (mysqli_affected_rows()>0){

echo "<script type='text/javascript'>
            alert('¡Tabla Finalizada!');
            </script>";
            include("Pasar_r_p.php");
}
else{

echo "<script type='text/javascript'>
            alert('¡La Tabla Ya Fue Finalizada!');
            </script>";
```

}

?>

Answer (score 1):

Si revisas [la documentación oficial en el sitio de PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli.affected-rows.php), notarás que en el apartado del estilo procedimental como el que tú estás desarrollando; la función requiere un argumento el cual es *el nombre de la variable que guarda la conexión*

Entonces quedaría:

```
mysqli_affected_rows($conexion)>0
```

Comment: Gracias, pude resolver el error.